# deploy azure logic apps independent of each other

Tags: release, release-management, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

i have 4-5 logic in single solution.

I want to deploy all to XXX environment initially so have created the build and release on the project and with continuous intigration am able to deploy all using azure resource group deployment task by passing logicdeploy.json and parameter.json files for each logic app in each task.

But now i got a change request for only 1 logic app and i have to deploy only that logic app. If i modify the file and commit due to CICD all the logic apps will get deployed.

How can i achieve this? deployed logic apps independent of each other.

This may be a basic question but i am struck at this point and am not able go forward.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have two strategies: (a) keep a single pipeline and add logic to check if an app has changed and needs to be deployed or (b) break down your pipeline in 5.

IMHO this latter is the simplest to implement, especially if you split the Visual Studio solution in 5.

Comment: now i have 5 solutions under 1 repository, how to create build and release for each solution in single repository independently? please clarify.

Comment: I have used the include path option in build and release to solve this, Build will be happened on specified path now.